# Post NSNotification to new ViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, push-notification, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have Tabbed Application with 5 tabs.

App starts on tab with index 0

When my app recive push notification, i want to push new view controller in tab with index 1.

My code:

AppDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushData {
    UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabb.selectedIndex = 1;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushImage" object:@"this is my item id from pushData"];
}
```

ProfileViewController (tab index 1)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushImage:) name:@"pushImage" object:nil];
}

-(void) pushImage: (NSNotification*) notification {
    NSString* text = notification.object;
    NSLog(@"My id from pushData: %@", text);
}
```

My problem is that the ProfileViewController can not response to the notification, because the initialisation not already done, when the AppDelegate fire the notification.

If a manually open the tab 1 and switch back to tab 0 again, an then post the notification, it perfectly respons to it. So i need to post notification after the tab 1 is loaded, how can i hand this?

My solution of pushing new VC from AppDelegate in TabBarApplication

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushData {    
            // ...... 

            if([[pushData objectForKey:@"type"] integerValue] == 0){
                // ....
            }
            else if([[pushData objectForKey:@"type"] integerValue] == 2){
                [self handleLikePush:pushData applicationState:application.applicationState];
            }
}

-(void)handleLikePush:(NSDictionary *)pushData applicationState:(UIApplicationState) applicationState{

    //..

    DetailImageViewController *detailImage = [[DetailImageViewController alloc] initWithImageId:imageId];
        [self pushViewControllerToCurrentTab:detailImage];
    }

}

- (void)pushViewControllerToCurrentTab:(UIViewController *)vc{

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *selectedTabNC = (UINavigationController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController;

    if (selectedTabNC != nil) {
        [selectedTabNC pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"NavigationController not found");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Add observer from other class.

Comment: Can you please describe this solution a little bit deeper?
May be with code example, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

`addObserver:instanceOfOtherClass`

instead of `addObserver:self`

In appDelegate add these lines  :

```
ProfileViewController *pvController=[ProfileViewController new];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:pvController selector:@selector(pushImage:) name:@"pushImage" object:nil];
```

to this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushData {
      UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
      tabb.selectedIndex = 1;
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushImage" object:@"this is my item id from pushData"];

     //****   add here

     ProfileViewController *pvController=[ProfileViewController new];
    //[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:pvController selector:@selector(pushImage:) name:@"pushImage" object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushIamge" object:pvController];// userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1,2,3,4,5" forKey:@"categories_ids"]]; 
}
```

Comment: I am not the best... but getting better day by day :p

Comment: pushImage: does not push my new ViewController.

Comment: I think, when i call:`tabb.selectedIndex = 1;` i create new instance of ProfileViewController.

So the *pvController does not really belongs to tabviewController (index 1)

Is it right?

Comment: `pushImage:` is not pushing a new VC?

Comment: I updated my code, am getting confused--was my previous answer wrong?

Comment: You answer about observer was right, but i got problems with pushing new VC.
Here is my new solution: i push new VC direct from appDelegate.
<code>UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *selectedTabNC = (UINavigationController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController;

DetailImageViewController *detailImage = [[DetailImageViewController alloc] initWithImageId:imageId];
[self pushViewControllerToCurrentTab:detailImage];</code>

Comment: `-(void)pushViewControllerToCurrentTab:(UIViewController *)vc{
    
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *selectedTabNC = (UINavigationController *)tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    
    if (selectedTabNC != nil) {
        [selectedTabNC pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"NavigationController not found");
    }    
}`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the `addObserver:` method to your view controller's `init` method?

Comment: My UITableViewController at tabIndex 1 does not response to: `- (id)init{}`

Comment: Sorry, I meant whatever your class's dedicated initializer is (say `initWitCoder:` or `initWithNibName:...`)

Comment: u can call the viewdidload method from the viewcontroller method as well right? - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self viewDidLoad];
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: No, don't call `viewDidLoad` yourself - this method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory, so if you call it yourself as well it will be called twice.